# Is it possible to keep a local mirror of an FTP site with aria2?

Tags: wget, aria2

I have a website to which I have FTP access only (otherwise I'd use rsync for this) and I'd like to keep a local copy of it. At the moment I run the following wget command every once in a while

```
wget -m --ftp-user=me --ftp-password=secret ftp://my.server.com
```

When there are many updates it does get tedious with wget only having one connection at a time. I read about aria2 but couldn't find any hints as to answer the questions whether it would be possible to use aria2 as a replacement for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

No, according to the [aria2 docs](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#options) the option for downloading only newer files only works with http(s).

> --conditional-get[=true|false]
>
> Download file only when the local file is older than remote file. This function only works with HTTP(S) downloads only. It does not work if file size is specified in Metalink.